# Why is my CNN model overfitting?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, keras

I am using Keras to train a CNN model as below for OCR task. It has 46 classes with some 78,000 examples in total. Each class has equal no. of examples. Seeing, that validation error was going up, a quick search showed that the model was overfitting. So, I added the dropout layers and removed some layers. I tested it with It limited the overfitting slightly but still the model overfits after some epochs. I tested with some variations but the trend is similar with validation accuracy seems to stop at ~.02 and validation error getting worse. Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```python
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 3)))
model.add(Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', strides=(1,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(144, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(46, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer="Adadelta", metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Training results:

```python
62560/62560 [==============================] - 6s - loss: 15.5154 - acc: 0.0305 - val_loss: 16.1079 - val_acc: 6.3939e-05
Epoch 2/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 15.1607 - acc: 0.0501 - val_loss: 15.7795 - val_acc: 0.0204
Epoch 3/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 14.6713 - acc: 0.0772 - val_loss: 15.7587 - val_acc: 0.0212
Epoch 4/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 14.2172 - acc: 0.0994 - val_loss: 15.7280 - val_acc: 0.0217
Epoch 5/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 13.7012 - acc: 0.1225 - val_loss: 15.7533 - val_acc: 0.0205
Epoch 6/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 13.4010 - acc: 0.1306 - val_loss: 15.7496 - val_acc: 0.0208
Epoch 7/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 11.4178 - acc: 0.1267 - val_loss: 5.9195 - val_acc: 0.0196
Epoch 8/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 4.0395 - acc: 0.0515 - val_loss: 4.6731 - val_acc: 0.0198
Epoch 9/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.8222 - acc: 0.0458 - val_loss: 4.4824 - val_acc: 0.0192
Epoch 10/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.7936 - acc: 0.0485 - val_loss: 4.6039 - val_acc: 0.0199
Epoch 11/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.7754 - acc: 0.0495 - val_loss: 4.5338 - val_acc: 0.0198
Epoch 12/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.7656 - acc: 0.0513 - val_loss: 4.6942 - val_acc: 0.0203
Epoch 13/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.7504 - acc: 0.0535 - val_loss: 4.6317 - val_acc: 0.0202
Epoch 14/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.7448 - acc: 0.0530 - val_loss: 4.7129 - val_acc: 0.0200
Epoch 15/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.7377 - acc: 0.0562 - val_loss: 4.6958 - val_acc: 0.0205
Epoch 16/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.7269 - acc: 0.0600 - val_loss: 4.9782 - val_acc: 0.0207
Epoch 17/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.7193 - acc: 0.0606 - val_loss: 4.7774 - val_acc: 0.0206
Epoch 18/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.7079 - acc: 0.0630 - val_loss: 4.8615 - val_acc: 0.0205
Epoch 19/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.7000 - acc: 0.0658 - val_loss: 4.8694 - val_acc: 0.0205
Epoch 20/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.6911 - acc: 0.0684 - val_loss: 5.0777 - val_acc: 0.0205
Epoch 21/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.6821 - acc: 0.0713 - val_loss: 4.9727 - val_acc: 0.0204
Epoch 22/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.6659 - acc: 0.0754 - val_loss: 4.9894 - val_acc: 0.0204
Epoch 23/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.6528 - acc: 0.0784 - val_loss: 5.1009 - val_acc: 0.0206
Epoch 24/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.6439 - acc: 0.0800 - val_loss: 6.0815 - val_acc: 0.0212
Epoch 25/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.6384 - acc: 0.0832 - val_loss: 5.4393 - val_acc: 0.0205
Epoch 26/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.6113 - acc: 0.0883 - val_loss: 5.4142 - val_acc: 0.0205
Epoch 27/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.5986 - acc: 0.0927 - val_loss: 5.3680 - val_acc: 0.0206
Epoch 28/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.5859 - acc: 0.0945 - val_loss: 5.2954 - val_acc: 0.0206
Epoch 29/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.5925 - acc: 0.0923 - val_loss: 5.4587 - val_acc: 0.0206
Epoch 30/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.5649 - acc: 0.0975 - val_loss: 5.6845 - val_acc: 0.0205
Epoch 31/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.5553 - acc: 0.0995 - val_loss: 6.7532 - val_acc: 0.0196
Epoch 32/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.5953 - acc: 0.1059 - val_loss: 5.8451 - val_acc: 0.0206
Epoch 33/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.5231 - acc: 0.1065 - val_loss: 5.9717 - val_acc: 0.0205
Epoch 34/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.5117 - acc: 0.1091 - val_loss: 6.2294 - val_acc: 0.0205
Epoch 35/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.5055 - acc: 0.1108 - val_loss: 6.0856 - val_acc: 0.0203
Epoch 36/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.4875 - acc: 0.1130 - val_loss: 6.3182 - val_acc: 0.0207
Epoch 37/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.4788 - acc: 0.1151 - val_loss: 6.2881 - val_acc: 0.0205
Epoch 38/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.4838 - acc: 0.1141 - val_loss: 6.3116 - val_acc: 0.0205
Epoch 39/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.4705 - acc: 0.1181 - val_loss: 6.3390 - val_acc: 0.0205
Epoch 40/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.4545 - acc: 0.1207 - val_loss: 6.5663 - val_acc: 0.0206
Epoch 41/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.4555 - acc: 0.1201 - val_loss: 6.4602 - val_acc: 0.0209
Epoch 42/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.4315 - acc: 0.1246 - val_loss: 6.3524 - val_acc: 0.0206
Epoch 43/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.4235 - acc: 0.1266 - val_loss: 6.6556 - val_acc: 0.0205
Epoch 44/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.4294 - acc: 0.1279 - val_loss: 6.5271 - val_acc: 0.0207
Epoch 45/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.4460 - acc: 0.1287 - val_loss: 6.8675 - val_acc: 0.0207
Epoch 46/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.3956 - acc: 0.1305 - val_loss: 6.5386 - val_acc: 0.0208
Epoch 47/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.3859 - acc: 0.1328 - val_loss: 6.8650 - val_acc: 0.0207
Epoch 48/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.3656 - acc: 0.1361 - val_loss: 6.9698 - val_acc: 0.0207
Epoch 49/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.3639 - acc: 0.1377 - val_loss: 7.2205 - val_acc: 0.0208
Epoch 50/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.3570 - acc: 0.1390 - val_loss: 7.6807 - val_acc: 0.0212
Epoch 51/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.3579 - acc: 0.1385 - val_loss: 7.1617 - val_acc: 0.0208
Epoch 52/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.3636 - acc: 0.1322 - val_loss: 7.0801 - val_acc: 0.0208
Epoch 53/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.3642 - acc: 0.1319 - val_loss: 7.0819 - val_acc: 0.0208
Epoch 54/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.3558 - acc: 0.1325 - val_loss: 7.2601 - val_acc: 0.0208
Epoch 55/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.3486 - acc: 0.1348 - val_loss: 7.0712 - val_acc: 0.0208
Epoch 56/1000
62560/62560 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 3.3403 - acc: 0.1334 - val_loss: 7.5916 - val_acc: 0.0207
```

Comment: Maybe try augmenting the images to give yourself more samples. Did you normalize to a range of 0-1? Maybe try dropping down the classes into large categories and see how that fits, may suggest you need more data

Comment: On seeing the loss values, I recommend you to change the optimizer. Try `adam` or `sgd`

Answer (score 0):

First things first did you normalize your data? (pointed out by djk47463).

About your  validation results, suppose your classifier did nothing but a uniform random guess among your 46 classes: it should be right about 1/46=0.021 of the time. This is approximately what you are getting. So it's somewhat safe to assume that your model is not learning.

If your data set is properly scaled (say with channel-wise zero mean and 1 stddev) then I think **your model is just too small**.

Look for example a reference mnist model:
https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

It has around 20k parameters in the convolutional part and 1.2kk paramters in its fully connected layers.

In contrast, your model has:

- From the first layer (3*3*3+1)*4 = 112 parameters (four 3x3x3 filters and one bias for each filter)
- From the second layer (3*3*4+1)*8 = 296 parameters (eight 3x3x4 filters and one bias for each filter)
- From the fully connected layers 172k parameters

So you have a mere 408 parameters in your convolutional layers and 172k parameters in your fully connected layers.

You might get away with not so large fully connected layers, but I'd sure increase by that convolutional parameter count by at least 10 fold.

**TLDR**;
Try adding more convolutional layers, each with more filters,eg:

```
Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 3))
```

Comment: djk47463, maz, I took advice from you and normalized my data. And also I increased the convolution layer sizes (16 and 32). Still no luck. But when I used my testing data (with all the classes) as validation data, it gave a completely different result. The validation accuracy hit .75 in first 35 epochs while the training accuracy was .34. The training and testing loss are both decreasing. What's the cause?